# Background image not displaying correctly with css

Tags: html, css, image

I'm having a problem with an image not displaying correctly behind other icons. I'm applying two separate images to surround icons. The first one displays fine but the second one clips off at the bottom.

Here's the site, the error can be seen in the footer: http://everythingdisc.hubs.vidyard.com/

```
<div class="inner">
    <div class="icons">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/inscape-publishing?trk=company_name" id="linkedin">&nbsp;</a>
         <a href="https://twitter.com/everything_disc " id="twitter">&nbsp;</a>
         <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/InscapeChannelDev" id="youtube">&nbsp;</a>
    <div class="clear-left">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
#social-media .inner {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 74px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  background: url(http://www.everythingdisc.com/../images/footer-icon-bg-left.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#social-media .inner .icons {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 59px;
  padding: 15px 20px 0 0;
  background: url(http://www.everythingdisc.com/../images/footer-icon-bg-right.jpg) top right no-repeat;
}
```

Anyone know why the image isn't displaying property?

Comment: `#social-media .inner .icons { height: 59px; }` The height of that element should match the height of its parent (`height:74px` or `height:100%`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give same heights to both divs.

```
#social-media .inner {
display: inline-block;
height: 74px;
padding: 0 0 0 30px;
background: url(http://www.everythingdisc.com/../images/footer-icon-bg-left.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#social-media .inner .icons {
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
height: 74px;
padding: 15px 20px 0 0;
background: url(http://www.everythingdisc.com/../images/footer-icon-bg-right.jpg) top right no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the div displaying the left side of your image is 74px high but the div displaying the right half is only 59px high. In addition the left side div contains the right side div and has bottom padding of 30px which is probably messing up the display of right side. Try something like this... I don't have your icons so the positioning may be off but your images show up correctly now

```css
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 74px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  background: url(http://www.everythingdisc.com/../images/footer-icon-bg-left.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.inner .icons {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 74px;
  padding: 15px 20px 0 0;
  background: url(http://www.everythingdisc.com/../images/footer-icon-bg-right.jpg) top right no-repeat;
}
```

```html
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="icons">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/inscape-publishing?trk=company_name" id="linkedin">icon1</a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/everything_disc " id="twitter">icon2</a>
            <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/InscapeChannelDev" id="youtube">icon3</a>
            <div class="clear-left">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```